# outer join of multiple pandas databases in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outer-join

I have a dataframe per year from 2009 until 2016.
Each dataframe has two columns C_ID and a year column labeled respectively. I want to outerjoin all dataframes.

So for example

df_2009:

```
C_ID    2009
 A      456
 B      754
 C      332
```

df_2010:

```
C_ID    2010
 A      3454
 C      54
 E      234
```

I found this approach on other posts on stackoverflow:

```
dfs = [df_2009, df_2010, df_2011, df_2012, df_2013, df_2014, df_2015, df_2016 ]
from functools import partial
merge = partial(pd.merge, on=['C_ID'])

result = dfs[0]
for df in dfs[1:]:
     result = merge(result, df)
```

But unfortunately this is an inner join and it gets rid of all C_IDs that are not in all datasets. I need to do an outer join.

Comment: have you checked the documentation of `pd.merge`? There's a `how` keyword argument for that.

Comment: That worked - thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Thank You @cel, I added how='outer' and it worked

```
dfs = [df_2009, df_2010, df_2011, df_2012, df_2013, df_2014, df_2015, df_2016 ]
from functools import partial
merge = partial(pd.merge, on=['C_ID'], how ='outer')

result = dfs[0]
for df in dfs[1:]:
     result = merge(result, df)
```